# Comparing two data sets in R

Tags: r, compare

I've searched around here and google for hours and cannot find a solution to my problem.

I have two datasets containing genes. One dataset is my dataset (snap) and I need to see if these genes are in the second bigger data set (catalog). I want the second column in snap (proxy) and the 21st column from catalog. This is what my datasets look like;

```
> head(snap)
        SNP     Proxy Distance RSquared DPrime
1 rs4246511 rs7540233     4541    0.874      1
2 rs4246511 rs4970634    15768    0.874      1
3 rs4246511 rs4532801    18960    0.874      1
4 rs4246511 rs9438982    22242    0.874      1
5 rs4246511 rs9438979    25034    0.874      1
6 rs4246511 rs4414011    25868    0.874      1 

head(catalog)
        SNPS MERGED SNP_ID_CURRENT    CONTEXT INTERGENIC
1  rs7079041      0        7079041     intron          0
2  rs7244261      0        7244261 intergenic          1
3 rs10448044      0       10448044 intergenic          1
4  rs2610025      0        2610025 intergenic          1
5  rs1472147      0        1472147     intron          0
6  rs2648708      0        2648708     intron          0
```

*This is a small part of the datasets

To make it more complicated, I'd also like to be able to pull the whole row of data from both data sets.

For the first part of my question I have tried using comparison (which I found from another similar question here). I decided to extract the columns I needed to simplify things (proxy is my column from snap and catalogsnps is the column from catalog);

```
    comparison <- compare(proxy, catalogsnps, allowAll=TRUE)
comparison$tM

difference <- data.frame(lapply(2:ncol(proxy),function(i)setdiff(cacheGenericsMetaData[,i],comparison$tM[,i])))
colnames(difference) <- colnames(proxy)
write.table(difference, file="difference.csv", sep=";", dec=".")
```

However with this syntax my output is simply a list of all my SNPs from snap.

Output

```
1054  6267
1055  6273
1056  6297
1057  6297
1058  6314
1059  6331
1060  6340
1061  6345
1062  6346
1063  6350
1064  6364
1065  6412
1066  6417
1067  6417
1068  6430
```

Since this was hard to read, I added the line to get the excel file, this looks like this;

```
x   
1   rs7079041
2   rs7244261
3   rs10448044
4   rs2610025
5   rs1472147
6   rs2648708
7   rs11891
8   rs1801725
9   rs6852678
10  rs3135758
11  rs6838240
12  rs6838240
13  rs603894
14  rs3764796
15  rs3764796
16  rs2073214
17  rs4971100
18  rs4971100
19  rs11718502
20  rs10888073
21  rs7032317
```

I also found another possible solution on here, but I again only got a list of my SNPs.

```
rows.diff <- function(catalog, proxy)
{
  catalogsnps.vec <- apply(catalogsnps, 1, paste, collapse="")
  proxy.vec <- apply(proxy, 1, paste, collaspse= "")
  rows.diff <- catalogsnps[!catalogsnps.vec %in% proxy.vec,]
  return(rows.diff)
}
write.table(rows.diff(catalogsnps, proxy), file="rowdiff.csv", sep=";", dec=",")
```

For the second part of my question, I am completely lost about where to start

Many thanks for any help

Claire

Comment: could you add some sample output of your data to this question `dput(head(proxy))`

Comment: I have edited my post with the output, I think this is what you meant?

Comment: No Claire, he asked for the output of the code he gave. That's a way to share a sample of your input data to be read into R.

Comment: It's close Claire, but what would be helpful to people looking at your question is a sample of data from your rows and columns from the data frames you are trying to compare. the dput function would allow other people to work with your data, but if you could include an example from each dataset `head(snap)` and `head(catalog)` it would give us a better indication of the data you're working with and the elements you're trying to compare

Comment: Ah ok, I've added that now thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just:

```
new.data <- merge(snap, catalog, by.x='proxy', by.y='catalogsnps')
```

This should give you a new dataframe whose rows are only the rows where proxy and catalogsnps match, and whose columns include all of the columns from the original dataframes.

Comment: What if you just run the third row above?  (The first two are superfluous, but I thought they might be clarifying).  Meaning, change the third row to: 
`new.data <- merge(snap, catalog, by.x='proxy', by.y='catalogsnps')`

Comment: I get a new error; "Error in fix.by(by.x, x) : 'by' must specify a uniquely valid column"

Comment: There is at least one capitalization error.  It looks like `snap` has a column named `Proxy`, not `proxy`.  Later on in your post, you discussed the column proxy in the lower case, hence my error.

Comment: also, looking above, it looks like `catalog` does NOT have a column `catalogsnps`, but instead has a column `SNPS`.  

Am I correct that you are trying to match `snap$Proxy` to `catalog$SNPS`?

So you would need: `new.data <- merge(snap, catalog, by.x='Proxy', by.y='SNPS')`

Comment: Yeah that's correct, I realised that as I was typing it into my syntax and changed it. The problem was the capital letter

Comment: I don't think all the results are retrieved, I know there are at least 10 SNPs that are the same (although I expect more) but this only shows 8 that are the same, any ideas why this is?

Comment: My first guess would be a (potentially subtle) non-match between the datasets.  One dataset could list the SNP with a space (potentially even a space next to it), or a difference in capitalization, etc.  Perform the following check: in the excel table, figure out what row in snap corresponds to the SNP (remember to account for the header row).  Call this row j, and confirm with `snap$Proxy[j]`.  Then find the same SNP (in excel) in catalog, determine the row (call this row k), and confirm with `catalog$SNPS[k]`. Then do `snap$Proxy[j]==catalog$SNPS[k]` to check if they really match or not.

Comment: catalog$SNPS[k] gives me a value of 0 (and not surprisingly an error; Error in Ops.factor(snap$Proxy[1303], catalog$SNPS[10372]) : 
  level sets of factors are different)

Comment: Ah I just realised there was a problem with the file, it was a tbs and something went wrong. I changed it to a cvs and now it works. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: You're welcome!  By the way, in my last comment there was a coding error, which accounts for the error that you saw (the comparison should have said 'FALSE' but not thrown an error).  I meant to write `as.character(snap$Proxy[j])==as.character(catalog$SNPS[k])`